# Continuity of $g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

Define $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}$.

Find the values of x where the series converges and show that we get a continuous
function on this set.

I can show $g(x)$ converges for $x \in (-1,1)$. $f_n(x) = \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}$ is obviously continuous on this set, so all I need to show $g(x)$ continuous is $\sum f_n \rightarrow g$ uniformly. The only thing I can think of is to use Weierstrass M-Test but I can't find the right $M_n$ s.t. $|f_n| \leq M_n$. Suggestions?

Comment: General member doesn't uniformly converge to $0$ on $(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sketch:** You can't prove uniform convergence on $(-1,1)$, because the series does not converge uniformly on $(-1,1)$. In point of fact, for $-1<x<1$: $$g(x)-\sum_{k=0}^n f_k(x)\ge\frac12\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty x^{2k}\ge 0$$ and $\sup\limits_{x\in(-1,\alpha]} \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty x^{2k}=\sup\limits_{x\in[\alpha,1)} \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty x^{2k}=\infty$ for all $\alpha\in(-1,1)$ and $n$.

However, what you can and should prove is uniform convegence *on compact subsets* of $(-1,1)$. For each $\beta>0$, you can make an uniform estimate on $[-\beta,\beta]$ in similar fashion as you'd do for $\sum_k x^{2k}$ (even use Weierstrass M-test, if you want).

Comment: How does $\sup\limits_{x\in(-1,\alpha]} \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty x^{2k}=\sup\limits_{x\in[\alpha,1)} \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty x^{2k}=\infty$? $\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} (x^2)^n$ is geometric with $|r| < 1$.

Comment: @chuckyeager Yes, it's $\frac{x^{2n+2}}{1-x^2}$ which diverges to $\infty$ as $x\to\pm1$.